# How enable nuxt build indicator for hot reload in development

Tags: nuxt.js, hot-reload

I want to see Nuxt.js hot reload progress indicator in my app development (https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#indicator), but I don't have it till the start of my app development. I upgraded my Nuxt version to the newest 2.12.2, but still I don't have it.
Could anyone help mi detect what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I didn't have it because I ran nuxt by this command in package.json:

`"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server"`

When I use just `"dev": "nuxt"` I have my hot-reload build indicator :)

Comment: Did you know why one show it and not the other one?

Comment: Nope. I guess that Nuxt has to run server by his own logic for fully use of its features.

Answer (score 1):

What does your nuxt.config.js look like?  The loading indicator is [on by default](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/#indicator), but can be controlled by the indicator property (nuxt.config.js > build > indicator)

Comment: `build: {
        extend (config) {
            config.node = {
                fs: 'empty'
            };
        },
        watch: ['nuxt.config.js']
    },`